# **tmux** in gnome terminal with sliding cursors in each pane

Tags: 17.04, gnome-terminal, ubuntu-gnome, tmux

I find tmux great and I use it all the time. 
However I am missing the sliding cursors when a cmd output is long enough that it wraps over the full pane height. Are scroll bars in each pane possible at all ? After snooping around for answer I think not.

Is the alternative to always use `[cmd] | less`, provided the output of [cmd] is predicted to be long ? It seems unsatisfactory.

Cheers.

Comment: What is a "sliding cursor"? Do you mean the scrollbar?

Comment: @egmont: Yes, exactly. Edited OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible. `GNOME Terminal` has a fixed UI structure, and makes its text grid canvas available for applications to write characters on. There is no way an application (e.g. `tmux`) could add other UI elements such as a scrollbar there.

(On macOS, `iTerm2` has something called "tmux integration". I don't know what it is, never tried, but it might include this feature you're looking for. None of the terminal emulators I'm aware of have it under Linux.)

Note that even with a single tmux pane only, the scrollbar is unusable (or depending on the graphical theme, probably not even visible). `tmux` switches to the so-called alternate screen of the terminal, which does not have a scrollback buffer. `tmux` offers its own means for scrolling – which also works when `tmux` presents multiple panes –, consult its documentation to find out what it is (sorry, I don't know off the top of my head).

If you don't need any of `tmux`'s features apart from the paned layout (multiple terminals next to each other), you might consider using `Tilix` or `Terminator` instead of `GNOME Terminal`. All these three (and many more) emulators are based on the `VTE` terminal emulator widget, so the actual terminal emulation behavior will be exactly the same, only the UI around it will be substantially different.

Comment: Looked at `tmux` man page and must have slept over when passing the section(s) on using mouse wheel to scroll or similar. Need to check again. Thanks for yr answer.

Comment: This answer should not be accepted as it completely missing the point.  In particular, tmux is actually provides a client-server API that a GUI program is able to utilize and actually construct its tabs/split screens according to the hints provided by tmux, *that is what the OP is asking about*. Unfortunately you've misguided the OP on the topic.

Comment: @AhmedMasud In that case: 1. I should study tmux's API. "a GUI program is able to utilize and actually construct its tabs/split screen" – and also to place a scrollbar, know the handle's height, and adjust the contents according to the handle's drag events? 2. The correct answer is then simply: "GNOME Terminal does not support this."